# Check if a file is over 30 days old WITHOUT the find command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've written a bash shell script and part of it is checks if a file is over 30 days old using the find command, sadly when I uploaded it to my host it did not work as the find command is locked down.

Does anybody know how to check if a file is over 30 days old  WITHOUT the find command?

I'm thinking I need to do an  "ls -a $filename" then parse the date string out, convert it to a unix date and then compare it with todays date but I'm very rusty at unix.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`stat -c %Z filename` gives the last change time in unixtime

`stat -c %Y filename` if you want the last modification time.

Comment: Hi thanks, I didn't know about that command. Should it be -f for format as -c isn't an option on my machine?

Comment: OK and how do you compare that to todays date to check if > 30 days?

Comment: Something like `$ts1=$(stat -c %Y filename); now=$(date '+%s'); ts2=$($now-3600*24*30);if [$ts1 -lt $ts2] ...` - but in any case @Ben Jackson's answer is better.

Comment: `ts1=$(stat -c %Y "$path"); now=$(date '+%s'); ts2=$(($now - 3600*24*30)); if [ $ts1 -lt $ts2 ]; then echo 'older'; fi` FTFY

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if [ $file -ot $timestamp_file ]` (`-ot` meaning "older than").  You would have to construct the appropriate file, for example with `touch` (which takes timestamp options).  If this is a periodic task you can also create the timestamp file on each run to use next time.

Comment: OK thanks, do you know how I'd get the date 30 days ago so that I can pass this into the touch command?

Comment: @The Frog Daddy: `touch -d "$(date -d '30 days ago')" 30DAYSAGO`

Answer (score 0):

Let `ls` output a unix timestamp, like this:

```
ls -l --time-style='+%s'
```

Then get the timestamp from the output, and simlpy calculate whether there are 30 × 24 × 60 × 60 seconds between the current time and the timestamp from `ls`.

You can get the current timestamp using

```
date '+%s';
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I can not get that command to work, I get "ls: illegal option -- -"

Comment: Sjoerd's solution implies a GNU ls -- which apparently poster does not have.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work in Linux: no -v option in date

```
t=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
let u=$t-1000000
touch -t "$u" $DATEFILE
if [ $SERVERFILE -ot $DATEFILE ]; then
  rm $SERVERFILE
fi
```

Comment: "That" refers to another answer. The order of the replies can change, so this should have been submitted as a comment - although you probably cannot comment yet.

Answer (score -1):

OK this is how I did it in the end...

1. I touched a file with a date of today - 1 month.

`touch -t "$(date -v -1m +%Y%m%d%H%M)" ${DATEFILE}`

1. Did an older than test on the 2 files.

`if [ ${SERVERFILE} -ot ${DATEFILE} ]`

Thanks everybody.